# Convert list of Dictionaries to comma separated string python

Tags: python

i'm trying to convert list of dictionaries to comma separated string , but some extra fields of dictionary are coming

```
data = [{'groupid': '28', 'name': 'TEST 2', 'internal': '0', 'flags': '0'}, {'groupid':'27', 'name': 'CUSTOMER/TEST 1', 'internal': '0', 'flags': '0'}]
```

expected output = `TEST2,CUSTOMER/TEST 1`

my script: `s = [','.join(map(str,i.values())) for i in data]`

output i'm getting : `['28,TEST 2,0,0', '27,CUSTOMER/TEST 1,0,0']`

Comment: Why is the expected output ```TEST2,CUSTOMER/TEST 1``` when you're printing all the key values from your dictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```py
data = [{'groupid': '28', 'name': 'TEST 2', 'internal': '0', 'flags': '0'}, {'groupid':'27', 'name': 'CUSTOMER/TEST 1', 'internal': '0', 'flags': '0'}]
print([d["name"] for d in data])
```

Output:

```
['TEST 2', 'CUSTOMER/TEST 1']
```

Answer (score 2):

For the expected out, you simply need to get the value corresponding to the key `name`:

```
s = ','.join(i['name'] for i in data)
```

Comment: You can drop the square brackets if you're using `.join()`. -> `','.join(i['name'] for i in data)`

Comment: thanks for the feedback, btw do you know if there is any difference wrt efficiency between the two?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but for large objects generator expressions are going to be more memory efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Data is defined as dictionary object. Apply elt for filter.

```
data = [{'groupid': '28', 'name': 'TEST 2', 'internal': '0', 'flags': '0'}, 
      {'groupid':'27', 'name': 'CUSTOMER/TEST 1', 'internal': '0', 'flags': '0'}]

expected output = [elt["name"] for elt in data]
print(expected output)
output = ['TEST 2', 'CUSTOMER/TEST 1']
```